# how to use more then one content type filter in same views in drupal 7?

Tags: views

I have two content types animal and fruits.
In animal content type fields description .
content type = animal

conditions:

date = 2015
user = login 
If a record exists that satisfies the above 2 conditions:

show description..

Then the system should then get the “body” data field value  from the content type “fruit” where the following 2 conditions are satisfied:

•   “Type” date field value = “apple” AND 
•   “Title” data field value = “appple is my fav”.

then body show "
for ex : some content like fsdf lfdjldf

Answer (score 0):

You need to add both the content-type inside ***Filter Criteria***.

- Click on the "Add/Or, Rearrange"
- Create new filter group

[image]

[image]